# How to execute python script on Visual studio / Other Editor with Linux environment

Tags: linux, python

as all know it is impossible to write long python script directly on Linux machine with vi editor

so we use (win editor) tools as visual studio / Pycharm and so on ....

so my question is how to execute python script on WIN from Visual studio with Linux environment?

For example

The following python code was written on the visual studio

```
import os
f = os.popen('date')
now = f.read()
print "Today is ", now
```

Usually after I write the code on the visual studio, then I send the python file to the Linux machine and I run the python  on Linux environment

And that because we cant run python code that fit for linux on win

Please advice if there are some alternative to run the python on Visual studio or other editors with Linux environment?

Comment: I write all my python code using vi on a linux machine, so I definitely don't agree with the first sentence at least.  Also, why can't you save that to a file and run it on Linux?  Copying that to a file and running `python sample.py` worked fine on my Linux machine, so what is it that's preventing you from running it?  Perhaps an example that doesn't work and the accompanying error message would help

Comment: sorry but I don't agree , there are many problem as indenting and so on , so from VI you cant see if your syntax is wrong , working from vi is not good idea

Comment: Alright, that's not really relevant to your question though, so we'll just disagree about that.  What is actually preventing you from running your python code on a linux system after writing it with Visual Studio?  The code you provided runs fine on my linux system, so I still don't understand the question